# How can I show the Text and Label in the CityDetailVC in swift?

Tags: swift

Cities

```
import Foundation
struct City {
    var image:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    var text:String = ""
    
    init(image: String, name: String, text: String){
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

CityCollectionView

```
class CityCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cityImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityNameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

CityCollectionVC

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CityCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    @IBAction function unwindToMain(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        
    }
    
    private var cities : [City] = [ City(image: "America", name: "America"),
                                    City(image: "Australia", name: "Australia"),
                                    City(image: "Austria", name: "Austria"),
                                    City(image: "Bangladesh", name: "Bangladesh"),
                                    City(image: "Belgium", name: "Belgium"),
                                    City(image: "Canada", name: "Canada"),
                                    City(image: "China", name: "China"),
                                    City(image: "Czech Republic", name: "Czech Republic"),
                                    City(image: "France", name: "France"),
                                    City(image: "Germany", name: "Germany"),
                                    City(image: "Hungary", name: "Hungary"),
                                    City(image: "India", name: "India"),
                                    City(image: "Korea", name: "Korea"),
                                    City(image: "Luxembourg", name: "Luxembourg"),
                                    City(image: "Netherlands", name: "Netherlands"),
                                    City(image: "Russia", name: "Russia"),
                                    City(image: "Slovakia", name: "Slovakia"),
                                    City(image: "Switzerland", name: "Switzerland"),
                                    City(image: "italy", name: "Italy"),
                                    City(image: "UK", name: "United States"),
                                    City(image: "Vietnam", name: "Vietnam")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override function numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override function collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return cities.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! CityCollectionViewCell
    
        // Configure the cell
        
        let city = cities[indexPath.row]
        cell.cityImageView.image = UIImage(named: city.image)
        cell.cityNameLabel.text = city.name
    
        return cell
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
        
    }

    override function prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems{
                let destinationController = segue.destination as! CityDetailViewController
                destinationController.city = cities[indexPaths[0].row]
                collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPaths[0], animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

CityDetailVC

```
import UIKit

class CityDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet var cityImageView:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    
    var city: City?
    var textView = ""
    var label = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       // cityImageView.image = UIImage(named: city?.image ?? "")
        cityImageView.image = UIImage(named: city?.image ?? "")
         
        
        
    }
    
}
```

**I'm a beginner in swift. I don't know how to show the label and text in city detailVC.** I tried but the thing is image is only showing in city detailVC not the label and text. Please guide me and give some example codes.
I don't know where to use the label and text. I didn't gave any label and text (content) for showing it in detail VC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `init` method in `City` is not needed and at least `name` and `image` are constants

```
struct City {
    let image : String
    let name : String
    var text : String = ""
}
```

In `didSelectItemAt` pass the `indexPath` and deselect the item

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Replace `prepare(for` with

```
override function prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "showDetail" else { return }
    let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
    let destinationController = segue.destination as! CityDetailViewController
    destinationController.city = cities[indexPath.row]
}
```

In `CityDetailViewController` just assign `name` and `text` like the image

```
class CityDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var cityImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    
    var city: City!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        cityLabel.text = city.name
        cityTextView.text = city.text
        cityImageView.image = UIImage(named: city.image)
    }
}
```

As all properties in `City` are non-optional the optionals are not needed.
And you can even omit the `image` string if the image name matches the city name.